Relation between solution spaces and vector space
there is a linear algebra question in front of me and it goes:
"Let W be the space spanned by the vectors: v1, v2, v3 (they are numerically given as 4x1 vectors.)
Find a homogenous system whose solution space is equal to W."
In the solution it simply finds null spaces, and writes them in the form x-(y+z)=0
My question is, why null space of my spanning vectors give me the vector space W? Or in this question to find W, am I taking null space for 2 times?
Could someone explain it on normal vectors and R3?
If my vectors are (1,0,0) (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) then my null space would be zero vector. How can I come to relation that my vector space must be R3 then? or is the zero vector's solution space being R3 making them compatible?
Thanks!

Remember: the null space of a matrix/linear map $T$ is the collection of vectors $x$ for which $Tx = 0.$ This is a homogeneous equation!

I still can not see the relation what is connecting the null space and vector space, sorry :/

Can you show that the null space is a vector space in its own right?

A system of homogeneous equations is of the form $Ax=b$. The nullspace is the special case when $b=0$. So the solution space of the equations and the nullspace are two descriptions of the same thing subspace.


Why are you speaking of $\Bbb R^3$? (Assuming your 3 vectors are linearly independent) $W$ is a hyperplane of $\Bbb R^4$. It is of dimension $3$ but is not equal to $\Bbb R^3$. 2) "null space of my spanning vectors" make no sense. 3) (Assuming again your 3 vectors are linearly independent) the equation of $W$ is of the form $\phi(v)=0$, where $\phi$ is the non-zero linear form determined (up to a multiplicative constant) by $\ker\phi=W$, i.e. $\phi(v_1)=\phi(v_2)=\phi(v_3)=0$.

